# Where could this CSS attribute be set?

Tags: css, height

I have a site that I've inherited, and am going a bit insane with the CSS. There's a div that has a height of 185px - it shows in Computed Styles, and it's very obviously being applied to the divs with the same class. However, the height doesn't show up anywhere in the stylesheet, and it doesn't show up under Applied Styles or Inherited From in the element inspector. (See screenshot.) I need to get rid of the height, as it's causing some issues with truncating content (we don't want to use overflow:scroll because there are many of these divs on the page - one per database record - and that's an awful lot of scrollbars.)

The div class is search-result, and you can see in the right pane the height:185px attribute. Here's the code we actually have in our stylesheet for that class plus sub-elements:

```
#content .search-result {
margin-bottom: 1em;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 1em 0;
}
#content .search-result .image-box {
float: right;
margin: 0 0 1.5em 30px;
font-size: .75em;
text-align: center;
}
#content .search-result .image-box img {
border: 1px solid #eee;
margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#content .search-result ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

I've also run grep on the entire site install, and the text "185px" doesn't exist anywhere on the server that I can find. Where else could this "ghost" style be getting set?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked for just "185", without "px"? And may be it is calculated and set somewhere in javascript then?

Comment: the div's height of 158px only accounts for the content's height. I'm guessing the computed height of 185px is after you apply the padding, border and margin.

Comment: @Draco - yes, I've looked for just 185, same results - doesn't exist. @kei - the 158px was a typo; I transposed the numbers. It's 185 all the way through, and I can't find where it's being set.

Comment: @Draco - also, if it was being calculated, I wouldn't think that every single instance of the div would have the exact same height, given that the content of each varies in length. I also don't think we're using any js that would do something like that, but I'll look.

Comment: Do you have this site online somewhere, for us to check it out?

Comment: @Draco - nope, it's an intranet site. If I can't get if figured out within the next hour, I'll try to post the rendered page to my personal host.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your CSS, it looks like 'em' units are being utilized, which looking at chrome's element inspector, it shows the unit as 'px', even when I explicitly list it as 'em'. Check around for height values declared in 'em' as well. Also I recommend using the "Styles" dropdown below computed styles to figure out which specific rules could be setting the height.

Comment: I'll look for ems, but there's nothing in our stylesheet anywhere that explicitly sets a height property, regardless of what unit it's using. And again, I've looked at the Matched CSS Styles that displays under the computed styles. None of them have a height property.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, I'd say that, because "div.search-result" has no declared height, it's expanding to the height (plus any padding, margins, borders, etc.) of the "div.image-box" and anything else that is a descendent of "div.search-result".

Comment: But it's not expanding; that's the problem. There are child elements that are overflowing div.search-result. If it were to expand to the size of all the child elements, there would be no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. Height could have been set to the child elements. Check for them.
2. Check if any other unit of measurement, like %, em have been used.

Checking the css values in computed styles won't help you. Check in the CSS tab

Comment: I posted the style code for the child elements in the original post; if you look you'll see that there's no height attribute for any of them. Also, there is no CSS tab in Chrome's element inspector. If you mean the Matched CSS rules, again - read the original post. I already stated there that none of the styles displayed there have a height attribute.